# ReferenceError: test is not defined with Jest

Tags: node.js, jestjs, referenceerror

I am trying to run the most basic example with Jest, yet I don't seem to be able to.
Followed the instructions here: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/getting-started.html

- npm init -y (for a base project)
- npm install --save-dev jest
- create sum.js file.
- create sum.test.js file.
- update "test" script.
- npm run test.

Boom, reference error. What am I missing here?

- npm v6.13.7
- node v10.13.0
- jest v26.0.1

This is my console output:

```html
FAIL  ./sum.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run
    ReferenceError: test is not defined
      1 | const sum = require('./sum');
      2 |
    > 3 | test('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', () => {
        | ^
      4 |   expect(sum(1, 2)).toBe(3);
      5 | });
      at Object.<anonymous> (sum.test.js:3:1)
    Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.957 s
Ran all test suites.
(node:21384) ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is experimental
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! test@1.0.0 test: `jest`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the test@1.0.0 test script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems related to this issue: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/9538

Try upgrading your node version to at least v10.14.2 or downgrading jest to at most v25.2.2.

Comment: Friend, thank you so much! I don't know why I had such an older version of Node, but after updating it to v12.17, everything works! =)